# Different Android Studio import workflows

Tags: import, android-studio

It seems something changed recently for Android Studio imports.  I now get two different dialogs that perform different workflows within Android Studio.

Sometimes I get this dialog:

[image: Android Studio import dialog]

And other times I get this dialog:

[image: Android Studio Eclipse import dialog]

This second dialog seems to appear when I import Android code even if it didn't come from Eclipse originally.  I know the code in question didn't come from Eclipse because I have imported older projects that I created using IntelliJ IDEA.

Does anyone know what Android Studio looks for when importing projects to bring up one dialog or the other?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Second  dialog is shown for non gradle or ADT based projects no matters using which IDE they are developed.

Answer (score 0):

At the present time it looks for the presence of an **AndroidManifest.xml** at the root directory of the project, and also the existence of either the **.classpath** and **.project** files (which are Eclipse project files) or the **res** and **src** directories.

This will likely change in future versions.